# ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError) bad response Forbidden 403

Tags: ruby-on-rails

when i run `gem install rails -v 5.1.4`

I get the following error

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    bad response Forbidden 403 (http://api.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/nokogiri-1.13.3-x64-unknown.gemspec.rz)
```

Thank you for your ahead of time!

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem due to TWO factors:

1. I am running everything inside an M1 architecture
2. I am running gem install inside an rbenv controlled directory

I will assume you are in the same spot like me (Specially the M1 architecture).

I was able to install nokogiri (and other gems) by using the `arch` command:

```
$ arch -x86_64 gem install nokogiri
Successfully installed nokogiri-1.12.5-x86_64-darwin
Parsing documentation for nokogiri-1.12.5-x86_64-darwin
Done installing documentation for nokogiri after 2 seconds
1 gem installed
```

I hope it works for you too.